# get class field from function input | Javascript / Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say that I have a class with public fields field1 and field2 which are strings

I want to have a function that takes 2 parameters, the first is the field and the second is the new string.

Can I create an enum for field1 and field2 and someone link the enum to the field so that whenever I use the function

```
function(FIELDS.field1, "newString")
```

It will know that FIELDS.field1 relates to this.field1 and FIELDS.field2 relates to this.field2.

basically my question is can I create a dynamic setter? because sure I can do

field1Setter and field2Setter but I will have a let of fields and do not want to create a setter for each

Comment: How would you reference a field with a variable? bracket notation.....

Comment: So true, idk how I forgot this. Thanks